# Is the entropy $S$ a fundamental equation of a system?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, entropy

I want to check if a given function for the entropy $S$ is a valid fundamental equation of a system. I don't know how to check whether or not the 2nd and 4th postulate of thermodynamics is obeyed by S.

The 2nd postulate states that $S$ has the properties:$S$ is defined for all equilibrium states. Given no constraint, the extensive variables (volume $V$, inner energy $U$ and species of particles $N_1,...,N_m$) take on certain values $x_i$. $S$ is maximized if the constraint is given and the extensive variables take on values $x_i$.

The 4th postulate says that the entropy $S$ vanishes for the state $(\partial U/\partial S)_{V,N_1,..N_m}=0$.

I can give a specific example: $$ S(U,V,N)=A(NVU)^{1/3},$$
where $A$ is a constant.

I calculated 
$$
\left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial S}\right)_{V,N}=\frac{3S^2}{A^{3}NV}.
$$
I can see that if $S\rightarrow 0$, that quantity also vanishes but is that enough?

I have no idea what to do with the 2nd postulate.

Comment: I have no idea what this "4th postulate of thermodynamics" is that you're referring to. Normally, thermodynamics is explained in terms of only three laws. Perhaps you could link to the source you're using or (better) quote the postulates as it states them.

Comment: 'Postulate IV: The entropy vanishes in a state for which it is true that: $$\left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial S}\right)_{V,\{N_i\}}=0.$$ (i.e. when temperature = 0)'

Comment: @ty where did you get it from? Reference, please.

Comment: Looks like the problem is from Callen's book.

Comment: @Tajimura It's from a handwritten lecture note of my prof.  The  lecture is  about thermodynamics and statistical physics.